# Big-O notation of 8^log2(n)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, computer-science, complexity-theory

I'm confused about what the big-O notation of `8^(log2(n))` would be.

Would you just be able to change it to `O(8^n)` since the `log2` would somewhat act as constant that just reduces the value of n? or would it be something else?

In a somewhat similar case what would be the big-O for `log2(n^n)`. would this just be `O(log2(n))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll need the following properties of logs and exponents to understand this one:

> 1. b<sup>Log<sub>b</sub>(x)</sup> = x
> 2. k . Log<sub>b</sub>(x) = Log<sub>b</sub>(x<sup>k</sup>)
> 3. (x<sup>a</sup>)<sup>b</sup> = x<sup>a.b</sup>

---

For the first problem:

> 8<sup>Log<sub>2</sub>(n)</sup>
>
> = (2<sup>3</sup>)<sup>Log<sub>2</sub>(n)</sup> (because 8 = 2<sup>3</sup>)
>
> = 2<sup>3 . Log<sub>2</sub>(n)</sup> (using Prop#3)
>
> = 2<sup>Log<sub>2</sub>(n<sup>3</sup>)</sup> (using Prop#2)
>
> = n<sup>3</sup> (using Prop#1)
>
> = **O(n<sup>3</sup>)**

---

For the second problem:

> Log<sub>2</sub>(n<sup>n</sup>)
>
> = n . Log<sub>2</sub>(n) (using Prop#2)
>
> = **O(n Log(n))**

Answer (score 0):

Big-O of `8^(log(n))`  will be `O(2^log(n))` as `8 = 2^3`.

Also `log(n^n) = n*log(n)`. So `big-O for log2(n^n)` would be `O(n*log2(n))`